# Access segmented control in table view cell from code ios

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control which i have created using story board. I want to change the height of it from code. How do i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

So the traditional way to do this would be to set the "tag" of the Segmented Control, so that in your tableView delegates you can access it by sending the cell "[cell.contentView viewWithTag:theTagNumber];" I cannot tell you exactly how you would do that with a story board created application as I don't use story boards.

So once you have the control, you change its frame. I'm not sure how it will look but this is how you do it:

```
UISegmentedControl *control = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:theTagNumber];
CGRect r = control.frame;
r.size.height = 50; // whatever you want
control.frame = r;
```

Comment: hmm. actually it is a static table so i dont have access to cell functions.

Comment: So by static you mean you create the cells you need during initialization, and don't do it "on the fly" as the table scrolls etc. The answer is still relative - each control in each cell needs a tag. If you can get a pointer to the cell object, you can then find the control using the method detailed above. If for some reason you cannot set the tag, then you can iterate through cell.contentsView.subViews and look for an object that passes "[view isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]" - but the tag is a much better way.

Comment: Basically i have created a static table view from story board. But for some reason it doesnt let me adjust the height of the segmented control in a cell. So i want to know how to resize it from code ? Thanks.

Comment: You obviously need to do this after the cells are created. So possibilities are viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. If that does not do it then you may need to make yourself the table delegate, then do it in "willPresentCell" - there is some delegate callback just before the cell is shown.

Comment: do i need to add the control back somehow or is the above code enough ?